# Exception - Maxmind geoip2

Tags: php

I'm using Maxmind GeoIP2 for monitoring traffic on my websites but my script is stopping on Fatal Error (I changed the IP address on 12.34.56.78):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: domain in /home/www/parser_only/ins.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: domain in /home/www/parser_only/ins.php on line 15
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GeoIp2\Exception\AddressNotFoundException: The address 12.34.56.78 is not in the database. in /home/www/parser_only/vendor/geoip2/geoip2/src/Database/Reader.php:248
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/parser_only/vendor/geoip2/geoip2/src/Database/Reader.php(217): GeoIp2\Database\Reader->getRecord('Country', 'Country', '12.34.56.78')
#1 /home/www/parser_only/vendor/geoip2/geoip2/src/Database/Reader.php(90): GeoIp2\Database\Reader->modelFor('Country', 'Country', '12.34.56.78')
#2 /home/www/parser_only/ins.php(115): GeoIp2\Database\Reader->country('12.34.56.78')
#3 /home/www/parser_only/ins.php(73): geo('12.34.56.78')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/www/parser_only/vendor/geoip2/geoip2/src/Database/Reader.php on line 248
run done
```

mentioned parts of code in VENDOR:

```
    /**
     * This method returns a GeoIP2 Country model.
     *
     * @param string $ipAddress an IPv4 or IPv6 address as a string
     *
     * @throws \GeoIp2\Exception\AddressNotFoundException  if the address is
     *                                                     not in the database
     * @throws \MaxMind\Db\Reader\InvalidDatabaseException if the database
     *                                                     is corrupt or invalid
     *
     * @return \GeoIp2\Model\Country
     */
    public function country($ipAddress)
    {
        return $this->modelFor('Country', 'Country', $ipAddress);
    }
```

```
    private function modelFor($class, $type, $ipAddress)
    {
        list($record, $prefixLen) = $this->getRecord($class, $type, $ipAddress);

        $record['traits']['ip_address'] = $ipAddress;
        $record['traits']['prefix_len'] = $prefixLen;

        $class = 'GeoIp2\\Model\\' . $class;

        return new $class($record, $this->locales);
    }
```

```
    private function getRecord($class, $type, $ipAddress)
    {
        if (strpos($this->dbType, $type) === false) {
            $method = lcfirst($class);
            throw new \BadMethodCallException(
                "The $method method cannot be used to open a {$this->dbType} database"
            );
        }
        list($record, $prefixLen) = $this->dbReader->getWithPrefixLen($ipAddress);
        if ($record === null) {
            throw new AddressNotFoundException(
                "The address $ipAddress is not in the database."
            );
        }
        if (!\is_array($record)) {
            // This can happen on corrupt databases. Generally,
            // MaxMind\Db\Reader will throw a
            // MaxMind\Db\Reader\InvalidDatabaseException, but occasionally
            // the lookup may result in a record that looks valid but is not
            // an array. This mostly happens when the user is ignoring all
            // exceptions and the more frequent InvalidDatabaseException
            // exceptions go unnoticed.
            throw new InvalidDatabaseException(
                "Expected an array when looking up $ipAddress but received: "
                . \gettype($record)
            );
        }

        return [$record, $prefixLen];
    }
```

and my code:

```
$sql .= "('". mysqli_real_escape_string($db, inet_pton($a[2])) ."','". geo($a[2]) ."','". mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim(substr($a[4], 0, strpos($a[4], 'HTTP')))) ."','". strtotime($a[3]) ."','{$a[6]}','{$a[1]}'),";
```

```
function geo($ip){
    $reader = new Reader(__DIR__ . '/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');

    // Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
    // "country".
    $record = $reader->country($ip);

    $geo = $record->country->isoCode . "\n";
    // $geo = geoip_record_by_name($ip);
     if($geo) return $geo;
     else return 'XX';
}
```

I am total noob, but I understand that I need somewhere implement this TRY-CATCH:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Can please somebody show me how and in which part? I guess in the last piece of code. But I am not sure how exactly these vendor parts work, because there are some exceptions already.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which of these is `ins.php`? And which is line 15?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```php
function geo($ip) {
    $reader = new Reader(__DIR__ . '/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');

    // Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
    // "country".
    try {
        $record = $reader->country($ip);
    } catch (\GeoIp2\Exception\AddressNotFoundException) {
        return 'XX';
    }

    $geo = $record->country->isoCode . "\n";
    // $geo = geoip_record_by_name($ip);
     if($geo) return $geo;
     else return 'XX';
}
```

Comment: \Exception $e instead of \GeoIp2\Exception\AddressNotFoundException looks like working ok. source: https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php/issues/16